# Specifying A List in the Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, model

The scaffold feature in MVC4 Visual Studio doesn't include the class 'CompatibleGames' in the context class after I scaffolded this model:

```
public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int CompatibleGamesId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int TotalDownloads { get; set; }
    [Range(0,5)]
    public int RatingOutOf5 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompatibleGamesId")]
    public List<CompatibleGames> compatibleGames { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category modCategory { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
```

Although when I changed the CompatibleGames property to a single instance, it did include the CompatibleGames Mode in the context class:

```
public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int CompatibleGamesId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int TotalDownloads { get; set; }
    [Range(0,5)]
    public int RatingOutOf5 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompatibleGamesId")]
    public CompatibleGames compatibleGames { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public Category modCategory { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
```

Is there any way to keep the List property, while letting the scaffold feature add the CompatibleGames model into the context class?

Comment: do you have a `many-to-many` relation between `Item` and `CompatibleGames`? Because scaffold does not support `many-to-many` relations

Comment: No, all I have is a primary key, do you need a foreign key attribute?

Comment: Can you add your `CompatibleGames` model?

Comment: I can add it to the context class, but I'd rather not as it involves generated code, and I'm not sure how it works

Comment: what I meant was if you could post the code for the `CompatibleGames` class